# Unable to retrieve newline chars from DB

Tags: php, mysql

I make DB entries from the PHP the following way.

```
<?php

 $receipt = "XXX XXX Solutions " . "\n";
 $receipt = $receipt . "           YYY  DELHI       " . "\n";
 $receipt = $receipt . "TxnId:-" . $txn_id . "\n";
 $receipt = $receipt . "Order Time: " . date("H:i:s") . "\n";
 $receipt = $receipt . "Date: " . date("d/m/Y") . "\n";
 $receipt = $receipt . "ItemDetails:" . "\n";
 $receipt = $receipt  . "" . "\n";

$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO cust_orders (session_id,txn_id,status,order_items,delivery,amount,customer_num,del_address, landmark, location, timeslot, dateslot, order_type, receipts) VALUES('%s','%s','PD','%s','HD','%s','%s','%s','%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",$session_id, $txn_id, $order_items_trimmed, $total, $mobilenumber, $address,   $landmark, $location, $timeslot, $dateslot, $order_type, $receipt);

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

I see database entries made correctly with new line characters.
However, when I retrieve the receipt, I get a continuous line without the '\n'.

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT receipts FROM cust_orders");
```

How do I get the correct receipts variable with \n.

Comment: if you print it out the html equivalent of the new line is `<br />`, you should do a search and replace before printing or use `nl2br()`

Comment: Show how are you printing the result of a query

Comment: you get the new line characters you just happen to be using html which expects well html so convert them wit `nl2br()`

Comment: $result = mysql_query($sql); $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); echo $row["receipts"];

Comment: I have to write receipts to a file in android. nl2br wont help since I would get </br> in my file everywhere.

Comment: there's no reason for the new line character to disappear, something else is going on show us the code writing to the file